# Is There Anyway to Fetch a Batch of Image to TFLite model on Edge TPU?

Tags: tensorflow-lite, google-coral

I am having trouble on some small detections on Coral Board and I have decided to use sliding window to cut the image in small sample images. But how can I fetch it to the edge_tpu model which only allow 1 image passing through?

Is there anyway to change the batch input when convert to TFlite model?

I have trained my model by **Object Detection API**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking for the code file [export_tflite](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/export_tflite_ssd_graph.py)
I switch to change the number of the batch from 1 to my desire number and everything is fine now.
Edit the batch from 2 files:
**export_tflite_ssd_graph_lib** and **export_tflite_ssd_graph_lib_tf1_test**

However, when join Edge TPU compiler, it can't run. Therefore, in order to run a batch of file, I run multiple single input instead and then I can run on edge TPU
[image]